# Celery not detecting new tasks in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery, flower

I have a django project with the following hierarchy:

```
.
├── api_v_1_0
├── celery_tasks
├── db.sqlite3
├── doc
├── manage.py
├── __pycache__
├── rockynode
├── run.sh
├── static
├── staticfiles
└── web
```

All the celery tasks are in the `celery_tasks` app :

```
celery_tasks
├── apps.py
├── emitter
├── __init__.py
├── mongo
├── __pycache__
├── rockynodemail
├── test
```

The `test` modules is a newly added module with tasks as follows:

```
from rockynode.celerys import celery_app_basic
class test:

    @celery_app_basic.task(queue='General')
    def s(x):
        return "{}"
```

The test module comprises of two files mainly:

```
celery_tasks/test
├── __init__.py
└── mytest.py
```

The content of `__init__.py` is as below:

`from .mytest import test`

However I cannot see the newly created task in my celery. For example if i do the following I dont see the `celery_tasks.test.s` task in the list:

```
from celery.task.control import  inspect
i = inspect()
i.registered_tasks()
```

Am I missing something in the process?

Comment: When you started the celery process did you pass the -Q General parameters so celery knows to look for another queue name besides the default?

Comment: Yes indeed i specified the queue: `celery -A rockynode worker --app=rockynode.celerys.basic -n basic.General -Q General --logfile=/var/log/celery/basic.General.log --pidfile=/tmp/basic.General.pid --loglevel=debug`

Comment: Does deleting the `__pycache__` folder and restarting your project help?